# Spring HibernateDaoSupport not enabling hibernate filters

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Why the HibernateDaoSupport is not enabling hibernate filters.I am trying to enable the filters in my code but not enabling.I have posted the spring and xml configuration files as below. I have provided all the files.

EmployeeHibernateDao.java :

```
public class EmployeeHibernateDao  extends HibernateDaoSupport  {

    public void saveDetails(Student s){

        getSession().merge(s);
    }

    public void getDetails(){

        Criteria ct= getSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
        getSession().enableFilter("addressFilter");

        List<Student> list = ct.list();

        for(Student s: list){

            System.out.println(s.getSname());       

      }
    }
}
```

student.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.spring.hibernatedao.Student" table="student24">
        <composite-id class="com.spring.hibernatedao.Address" name="address">
            <key-property name="addressNo" column="addressno" />
            <key-property name="addressName" column="addressname" />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="sname" column="sname" />
        <property name="date" column="inserteddate" />
        <filter name="addressFilter" condition="sname = 'hello'" />
    </class>
    <filter-def name="addressFilter" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="system" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="myssessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/com/spring/hibernatedao/student.hbm.xml</value>              
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">             
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>                  
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="empdao" class="com.spring.hibernatedao.EmployeeHibernateDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="myssessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ct=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/spring/hibernatedao/applicationContext.xml"); 

    EmployeeHibernateDao empdao= ct.getBean("empdao", EmployeeHibernateDao.class);  
    empdao.getDetails();

}
}
```

Comment: For starters you shouldn't use `HibernateDaoSupport` but use plain hibernate directly. This class stems from a past in which Hibernate didn't allow for easy integration. That being said I suggest to check what the `getSession` method actually does. In short you have 2 separate sessions. Call `getSession` once and reuse the given session.

Answer (score 0):

Add One below configuration into student.xml and try:

```
     <filter name="addressFilter" condition="sname = :addressFilterParam" />
 </class>
<filter-def name="addressFilter">
   <filter-param name="addressFilterParam" type="java.lang.String"/>
 </filter-def>
```